# method override fails when retrieving by base class

Tags: python, inheritance, orm, sqlalchemy, multiple-inheritance

I'm using the sqlalchemy module's orm features to store objects.  These objects are custom "Task" objects that perform arbitrary tasks.  When retrieving these objects for later execution, I use a base class to make the retrieval.  The other objects inherit from this class when they're created and inserted into the database.  Each one override's the part of the base class that does work.  Let's call this the work function.  Unfortunately, after retrieval, my objects execute the base class work function instead of the derived class.

It looks like this:

```
    class Parent():
      def work(self):
        print 'I am a parent'

    class Child(Parent):
      def work(self):
        print 'I am a child'
```

The sql alchemy session generation is like so:

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://root:@localhost:3306/mercury', pool_recycle=3600)

    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
    session = sessionmaker()
    session.configure(bind=engine)
```

Correct so far, I think. Insertion and retrieval look like this.

```
    sess = session()

    object = Child()
    sess.add(Child)
    result = sess.query(Parent).limit(1).one()
```

This is where it seems to fail.

`result.work()`

`I am a parent`

I'm also using a mixin to attach orm capability; not shown here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how SQLAlchemy works.  As far as SQLAlchemy can tell, there's no technical difference between `Parent` and `Child` at the database level, and therefore any row in either table can be loaded into the class.

You specifically asked for Parent to load, so it loaded.

I think the pattern you are looking for is here a [polymorphic identity](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/inheritance.html?highlight=polymorphic#single-table-inheritance).  This will create a column on your table which allows SQLAlchemy to tell the difference between the different classes and load the appropriate one.

Please note, however, a little quirk in polymorphic identity:

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'people'

    type_ = Column(types.String)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': None,
        'polymorphic_on': type_
    }

class Parent(Person):

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': "parent",
        'polymorphic_on': type_
    }

    def work(self):
        print 'I am a parent'

class Child(Person):
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': "child",
        'polymorphic_on': type_
    }

    def work(self):
        print 'I am a child'
```

The `None` polymorphic can be used to query for all types and will return the appropriate class, i.e.:

```
> session.query(Person).filter(Person.type_ == 'child').first()
Child(type_='child')
```

However, the reverse is not true.  This will **not** work:

```
> session.query(Parent).filter(Parent.type_ == 'child').one()
NoResultFound: No row was found for one()
```

In other words, be sure to make a base class with `'polymorphic_identity': None` if you would like to be able to query in a general fashion as you listed in your question.